# Onload download

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola quisiera saber como puedo hacer un script que apenas cargue la pagina comience una descarga, sin ningun

> <'a href="">

ni nada que implique clicks. Lo busque por todos lados pero no lo encontre. Saludos

Comment: por favor comparte lo que has intentado en código para ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utiliza el evento onload de window y apunta el location a la url de descarga

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
         window.location = 'url de descarga';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, mi granito de arena seria Intentar con algo asi:

En tu JS crea la function que efectue la descarga
Y el el html se haces el llamado de la function al cargar el body con el evento onload.

```js
function descarga() {
    window.location = 'http://www.jesuministrosymas.com.ve/LOGO.png';
}
```

```html
<body LANG="es-VE" DIR="LTR" onload="descarga();">
 
</body>
```